# Nested async/await functions

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to understanding how to use **async/await** in nested manner.
In the example, I am calling function a() and inside that, I want to call b() and ensure that b() resolves before a().
The following is the code and although b() is called, it is not getting resolved.

```js
function a() {
   b();
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('resolved a');
    }, 2000);
  });
}

function b() {
  console.log('calling b');
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('resolved b');
    }, 2000);
  });
}

 async function asyncCall() {
  console.log('calling');
  const result = await a();
  console.log(result);
}

asyncCall();
```

The output of the code above is:
"calling"
"calling b"
"resolved a" (This line shows up after **2 seconds**)

Then, I changed to code to include async/await in a(), (everything else is the same)

```js
async function a() {
   await b();
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('resolved a');
    }, 2000);
  });
}

function b() {
  console.log('calling b');
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('resolved b');
    }, 2000);
  });
}

 async function asyncCall() {
  console.log('calling');
  const result = await a();
  console.log(result);
}

asyncCall();
```

The output of the code above is:
"calling"
"calling b"
"resolved a" (This line shows up after **4 seconds** [In the previous example it was 2 seconds])

But in both the case, '**resolved b**' is not getting printed.

I have 2 questions:

1. How do I print '**resolved b**' ?
2. Is it common to have cases like this where an async function (in this case, function "a"), is both the callee (it is called by asyncCall()) and the caller (it is calling b()) ?

Comment: "resolved b" is not getting printed because nothing prints the result of `b()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I print 'resolved b' ?

Your code as it stands completely ignores the resolved value of `b`. The first example ignores the promise entirely. The second example waits for the promise to resolve but does nothing with the resolved value (not even capture it in a variable).

You have to `console.log()` it like you did everything else you logged.

You could `logthisvalue = await b()`. You could `b().then(logthisvalue => here)`. You could modify `b()` so it logs its own value.

> Is it common to have cases like this where an async function (in this case, function "a"), is both the callee (it is called by asyncCall()) and the caller (it is calling b()) ?

Yes.

The `async` and `await` keywords are tools to manage promises.

Top level `await` has poor support so, in general, you can only use `await` inside an `async` function.

You have to call an `async` function for it to do anything.

The `async` function has to get a promise to `await` from *somewhere* and usually that is by calling another function.